# phpでエクセルファイルをCSVファイルに変換したい

Tags: php, csv, excel

#### やりたいこと

PHPExelライブラリを使用し、サーバ側に保存されたエクセルファイルをcsvファイルに変換し、
新たにcsvファイルとして保存したい。

- サーバ側にすでに保存されたエクセルファイルのイメージ（juchuu.xls）

  ```
  item1 item2 item3
  2 3 6
  ```
- 新たに変換させたいcsvファイル

  ```
  item1,item2,item3
  2,3,6
  ```

#### 実際のプログラム

- サーバ側の該当フォルダにjuchuu.xlsが保存されている
- ライブラリとしてPHPEXLELのプログラム一式がサーバ側に保存されている

```
**<?php

echo "段階0";
require_once(DIR . "/lib/PHPExcel.php");
require_once(DIR . "/lib/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php");

echo "段階1";
// PHPExcelオブジェクトを生成する
$reader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader("Excel2007");

echo "段階2";
//Excel読み込み
book=book=objReader->load('./juchuu.xls');

echo "段階3";
//CSV保存
writer=PHPExcelIOFactory::createWriter(writer=PHPExcelIOFactory::createWriter(book, 'csv');
$writer->save('./juchuu3.csv');?>**
```

#### できないこと（結果）

- 段階2 まで表示された
- 当然、csvファイルも保存されていない。

#### おしえていただきたいこと

どこが間違っていますか？

#### 参考にした記事

[PHPExcelでxlsファイルをCSVに変換する - Qiita](https://qiita.com/hodade/items/13aa1df16bb5f4c2702a)

Comment: うまく動かない原因については私も詳しくないので直接回答できませんが、参照している記事は五年以上前のもので、PHPExcel 自体もメンテナンスがされていないので [PhpSpreadsheet](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet) の利用を推奨しているようです。

Answer (score 1):

cubickさんがすでにコメントされていますが、[PHPExcel](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel)では

> ## PHPExcel - DEAD
>
> ---
>
> PHPExcel last version, 1.8.1, was released in 2015. The project was officially deprecated in 2017 and permanently archived in 2019.
>
> The project has not be maintained for years and must not be used anymore. **All users must migrate** to its direct successor PhpSpreadsheet, or another alternative.

とありますから、従うべきかと思います。

---

> ```
> $reader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader("Excel2007");
> ```

とりあえず`Excel2007`はいわゆる`.xlsx`形式です。`.xls`形式を扱うのであれば[`Excel5`](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/1.8/Documentation/markdown/ReadingSpreadsheetFiles/01-File-Formats.md)を指定する必要があります。Qiita記事もそう指定されています。

（ちなみに[キータ](https://help.qiita.com/ja/articles/qiita)なので綴りに`u`が入り込む余地はありません）